# CriteriaBuilder, CriterilaQuery, Root. Где ошибка?

Tags: java, json, rest, postman

Всем привет.

Это RESTful [приложение](https://github.com/Nehoko/Lanit/tree/master/RESTfulCRUD), которое должно выполнять следующие [условия](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12QCnPgj5plb7vhrhPNt9jnTgMch3jdAdzoFx6MDBmps/edit#gid=0).

Вот сервис, который обрабатывает запрос POST("/car")

```
package ru.lanit.rest.service;

import ru.lanit.rest.dao.CarDAO;
import ru.lanit.rest.dao.PersonDAO;
import ru.lanit.rest.model.Car;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@RequestScoped
@Path("/car")
public class CarService {

    @Inject
    private CarDAO carDAO;

    @Inject
    private PersonDAO personDAO;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Transactional
    public Car addCar(Car car){
        car.setOwner(personDAO.getPerson(car.getOwnerId()));

        return carDAO.addCar(car);
    }

}
```

Вот CarDAO, который работает с БД:

```
package ru.lanit.rest.dao;

import ru.lanit.rest.model.Car;
import sun.awt.image.ImageWatched;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

@ApplicationScoped
public class CarDAO {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Inject
    private StatisticsDAO statisticsDAO;


    public Car getCar(Long id){
        return entityManager.find(Car.class, id);
    }

    public Car addCar(Car car) {
        statisticsDAO.getStatistics().incrementCarcount();
        entityManager.merge(car);
        entityManager.flush();
        checkVendorUniqueness();
        return entityManager.find(Car.class, car);
    }

    public  Car updateCar(Car car){
        entityManager.merge(car);
        entityManager.flush();
        checkVendorUniqueness();
        return entityManager.find(Car.class, car);
    }

    public void deleteCar(Long id) throws Exception {
        statisticsDAO.getStatistics().decrementCarcount();
        entityManager.remove(entityManager.find(Car.class, id));
        entityManager.flush();
        checkVendorUniqueness();
    }

    public List<Car> getAllCars(){
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Car> carCriteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(Car.class);
        return entityManager.createQuery(carCriteriaQuery).getResultList();
    }

    public void deleteAllCars() throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Car> cars = (ArrayList<Car>)getAllCars();
        while(!cars.isEmpty()){
            deleteCar((long) (cars.size()-1));
        }
    }

    private void checkVendorUniqueness(){
        long uvc = 0;
        LinkedList<Car> cars = (LinkedList<Car>)getAllCars();
        LinkedList<String> vendors = new LinkedList<>();

        while (!cars.isEmpty()){
            String[] vendor = cars.getFirst().getModel().split("-");
            vendors.add(vendor[0]);
            cars.removeFirst();
        }

        for(int i = 0 ; i<vendors.size(); i++){
            String vendor = vendors.get(i);
            boolean match = false;
            for (int j = i+1; i<vendors.size(); i++){
                String vendorTwo = vendors.get(j);
                if(vendor.equals(vendorTwo))
                    match = true;
            }
            if(!match)
                uvc++;
        }
        statisticsDAO.getStatistics().setUniquevendorcount(uvc);
    }
}
```

Сам класс Car:

```
package ru.lanit.rest.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name="car")
public class Car implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "model")
    @NotNull
    private String model;

    @Column(name = "horse_power")
    @NotNull
    private Integer horsepower;



    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    private Person owner;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ownerid")
    private Long ownerId;

    public Long getOwnerId() {
        return ownerId;
    }

    public void setOwnerId(Long ownerId) {
        this.ownerId = ownerId;
    }

    public Car(){}

    public Car(Long id, String model, Integer horsepower, Long ownerId){
        this.id = id;
        this.model = model;
        this.horsepower = horsepower;
        this.ownerId = ownerId;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        if(model.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"))
        this.model = model;
    }

    public Integer getHorsepower() {
        return horsepower;
    }

    public void setHorsepower(Integer horsepower) {
        this.horsepower = horsepower;
    }

    public Person getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(Person owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

Проблема, заключается в том, что при запросе POST /car в Postman и отправлении JSON команды:

```
{
    "id":3,
    "model":"BMW-X3",
    "horsepower":200,
    "ownerId":1
}
```

Выдаётся такая вот [ошибка](https://gist.github.com/Nehoko/81c42b47754bcacd346eb7cb89b5febb):

```
    ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3) UT005023: Exception handling request to /RESTfulCRUD/api/car: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error occurred validating the Criteria
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:149)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:372)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error occurred validating the Criteria
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:736)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.createQuery(AbstractEntityManager.java:116)
    at ru.lanit.rest.dao.CarDAO.getAllCars(CarDAO.java:54)
    at ru.lanit.rest.dao.CarDAO.checkVendorUniqueness(CarDAO.java:66)
    at ru.lanit.rest.dao.CarDAO.addCar(CarDAO.java:33)
    at ru.lanit.rest.dao.CarDAO$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.addCar(Unknown Source)
    at ru.lanit.rest.service.CarService.addCar(CarService.java:31)
    at ru.lanit.rest.service.CarService$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.addCar$$super(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceedInternal(TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:77)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:92)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleInterceptorInvocation.java:74)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeAroundInvoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:84)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:79)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:68)
    at ru.lanit.rest.service.CarService$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.addCar(Unknown Source)
    at ru.lanit.rest.service.CarService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.addCar(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No criteria query roots were specified
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl.validate(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:58)
... 69 more
```

Я так понял, проблема в CriteriaBuilder, CriteriaQuery и/или Root, но как решить её, я понять не могу.

Вопросы:

1. Почему возникает ошибка?
2. Как сделать так, что при отправлении в JSON
   "ownerId" привязывался к новой машине объект Person с указанным id?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или **ошибку** и **минимальный код** для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы **без явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

CarDAO, который был:

```
package ru.lanit.rest.dao;

import ru.lanit.rest.model.Car;
import sun.awt.image.ImageWatched;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

@ApplicationScoped
public class CarDAO {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Inject
    private StatisticsDAO statisticsDAO;


    public Car getCar(Long id){
        return entityManager.find(Car.class, id);
    }

    public Car addCar(Car car) {
        statisticsDAO.getStatistics().incrementCarcount();
        entityManager.merge(car);
        entityManager.flush();
        checkVendorUniqueness();
        return entityManager.find(Car.class, car);
    }

    public  Car updateCar(Car car){
        entityManager.merge(car);
        entityManager.flush();
        checkVendorUniqueness();
        return entityManager.find(Car.class, car);
    }

    public void deleteCar(Long id) throws Exception {
        statisticsDAO.getStatistics().decrementCarcount();
        entityManager.remove(entityManager.find(Car.class, id));
        entityManager.flush();
        checkVendorUniqueness();
    }

    public List<Car> getAllCars(){
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Car> carCriteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(Car.class);
        return entityManager.createQuery(carCriteriaQuery).getResultList();
    }

    public void deleteAllCars() throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Car> cars = (ArrayList<Car>)getAllCars();
        while(!cars.isEmpty()){
            deleteCar((long) (cars.size()-1));
        }
    }

    private void checkVendorUniqueness(){
        long uvc = 0;
        LinkedList<Car> cars = (LinkedList<Car>)getAllCars();
        LinkedList<String> vendors = new LinkedList<>();

        while (!cars.isEmpty()){
            String[] vendor = cars.getFirst().getModel().split("-");
            vendors.add(vendor[0]);
            cars.removeFirst();
        }

        for(int i = 0 ; i<vendors.size(); i++){
            String vendor = vendors.get(i);
            boolean match = false;
            for (int j = i+1; i<vendors.size(); i++){
                String vendorTwo = vendors.get(j);
                if(vendor.equals(vendorTwo))
                    match = true;
            }
            if(!match)
                uvc++;
        }
        statisticsDAO.getStatistics().setUniquevendorcount(uvc);
    }
}
```

CarDAO, который стал:

```
package ru.lanit.rest.dao;

import ru.lanit.rest.model.Car;
import sun.awt.image.ImageWatched;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

@ApplicationScoped
public class CarDAO {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    @Inject
    private StatisticsDAO statisticsDAO;


    public Car getCar(Long id){
        return entityManager.find(Car.class, id);
    }

    public Car addCar(Car car) {
        statisticsDAO.getStatistics().incrementCarcount();
        entityManager.merge(car);
        entityManager.flush();
        checkVendorUniqueness();
        return entityManager.find(Car.class, car.getId());
    }

    public  Car updateCar(Car car){
        entityManager.merge(car);
        entityManager.flush();
        checkVendorUniqueness();
        return entityManager.find(Car.class, car.getId());
    }

    public void deleteCar(Long id) throws Exception {
        statisticsDAO.getStatistics().decrementCarcount();
        entityManager.remove(entityManager.find(Car.class, id));
        entityManager.flush();
        checkVendorUniqueness();
    }

    public List<Car> getAllCars(){
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory();
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManagerFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Car> carCriteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(Car.class);
        Root<Car> carRoot = carCriteriaQuery.from(Car.class);
        carCriteriaQuery.select(carRoot);
        return entityManager.createQuery(carCriteriaQuery).getResultList();
    }

    public void deleteAllCars() throws Exception {
        LinkedList<Car> cars = (LinkedList<Car>)getAllCars();
        while(!cars.isEmpty()){
            deleteCar((long) (cars.size()-1));
        }
    }

    private void checkVendorUniqueness(){
        long uvc = 0;
        ArrayList<Car> cars = (ArrayList<Car>) getAllCars();
        LinkedList<String> vendors = new LinkedList<>();

        while (!cars.isEmpty()){
            String[] vendor = cars.get(cars.size()-1).getModel().split("-");
            vendors.add(vendor[0]);
            cars.remove(cars.size()-1);
        }

        for(int i = 0 ; i<vendors.size(); i++){
            String vendor = vendors.get(i);
            boolean match = false;
            for (int j = i+1; i<vendors.size(); i++){
                String vendorTwo = vendors.get(j);
                if(vendor.equals(vendorTwo))
                    match = true;
            }
            if(!match)
                uvc++;
        }
        statisticsDAO.getStatistics().setUniquevendorcount(uvc);
    }
}
```

При изменениях в методах addCar(Car car), updateCar(Car car), getAllCars() программа полетела и доставила огромное удовольствие разработчику :)